# I want to ignore validate hidden text field when submitting the form

Tags: magento2

I want to ignore validate hidden text field before submit form( when submit button clicks).
I have searched for solutions and reached this script. But it is not working, form is submitting before validation fires.

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#form_2');
    var ignore = '.field-12-other'; // class name of hidden input text field

    /*
        dataForm.mage('validation', {
            ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
        }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
        */

         dataForm.mage('validation', {
            ignore: ':hidden:(' + ignore + ')'
        }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

});
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require([
      "jquery",
      "mage/mage"
  ], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#review-form');
    dataForm.mage('validation', {ignore: ''});
})
</script>
```